# Django template unicode String comparison

Tags: python, django, string, templates, comparison

I have been stuck here for hours now and I hope someone here can help me.
I want to compare Strings in a Django template.
My view is giving two lists of Strings to the Template:

```
latest_app_list = App.objects.all().order_by('name')[:5]
context = {'latest_app_list': latest_app_list}
if not request.body == "":
    xml = ET.fromstring(request.body)
    interfaces = []
    for x in xml.getchildren(): 
        interfaces.append(unicode(x.text, 'utf-8'))                                                       
    context = {'latest_app_list': latest_app_list, 'xml': interfaces}
if("format" in request.GET.iterkeys() and request.GET['format'] == "xml"):
    return render(request, 'appstore/appstore.xml', context, content_type="application/xml")
```

In the tempate of appstore.xml now the Lists should be compared.

```
 {% if latest_app_list %}
  {% for app in latest_app_list %}
    {% if xml %}
      {% for interface in xml %}
        {% for app_interface in app.interfaces.all %}
          {% ifequal interface app_interface %}
            <app>
              <uri>{{app.ip}}</uri>
              <id>{{  app.id }}</id>
              <name>{{ app.name }}</name>
            </app>
          {% endifequal %}
        {% endfor %}
     {% endfor %}
    {% endif %} 
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

So the Template should only show the s, which have a interface in the given Interface-List.
Ich have already had a look at the types. Both are unicode Strings.
For reference, here is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
class Interface(models.Model):
 title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
 def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title

class App(models.Model):
 id      = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
 name    = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 description = models.TextField(max_length=3000)
 ip      = models.CharField(max_length=150)
 interfaces  = models.ManyToManyField(Interface)
 file    = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')                                                    
 def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to be comparing strings with strings. You're comparing a string with an `Interface` object. Maybe you meant `{% ifequal interface app_interface.title %}`?

Comment: It's always these little things, right? Thank you very much for opening my eyes.